# How to change default Dash Home name?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Is there is any possibility for Ubuntu 12.04 to change default "Dash Home" name to what ever.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can press super+a to open the Applications lense directly, super+f to open Files and Folders and super+m for Music.

Comment: Can't I change somehow "Dash Home" icon to open Applications lenses instead of pressing that buttom ?